# How to resolve conflicts in `project.pbxproj` file while upgrading react native?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am using Xcode 9.4 and current react native version @0.54.4 I want to upgrade the version to 0.55.4.

As I upgrade my project using `react-native-git-upgrade`, I see some un merged conflicts in the `project.pbxproj`. Some of the settings are my own that are conflicting with the changes in the new version.

I tried all the possible ways in which I could resolve the conflicts. But still X-code shows the error `could not load the project`, and it does not allow me to build my project.

How do I understand what those conflicts are referring to and how can I safely resolve the conflicts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no magic way to resolve conflicts. I wish there was. The file is managed by Xcode and from personal experience I have found that you can easily mess it up performing merges.

`Git` is definitely your best-friend. Make sure that before you start any merge you are on a new branch and fully committed so that if you mess-up you can easily get back to your original version.

What I usually do is keep the original version of the `project.pbxproj` and **then make the changes manually in Xcode**. I know this doesn't sound ideal but it does mean you should be able to open the project in Xcode, though your project may not run - just yet.

If you’re unclear about which version to keep, I would keep **ours** as that is the **original** version of your `project.pbxproj`. From the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading#4-resolve-the-conflicts):

> You can think of "ours" as "your team" and "theirs" as "the React Native dev team".

Then I would make the changes manually as detailed below. As that will show **their** changes and the should hopefully not be that many.

To help me find the changes that I have to make I find that [React Native Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) is an invaluable resource. There you can find a `git diff` of any two versions of `react-native` that you choose. (This saves you having to create two projects and then compare them yourself, a big timesaver.)

Currently you are upgrading from `0.54.4` to `0.55.4` this link shows the diff between those versions

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.54.4&to=0.55.4

For additional help you could create a project in a specific `react-native` version, using the following will create a project for version `0.55.4`.

`react-native init newproject --version react-native@0.55.4`

That way you can look inside the Xcode project to see what has been added, and where it was added from, as the `git diff` doesn't always tell where it came from.

I have never had much luck using `react-native-git-upgrade` and I have come to prefer doing it manually, as I have had much more success doing it that way.

Comment: [Kaleidoscope](https://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com) is magic to solve `project.pbxproj` problems.

Comment: @FlorentMorin I haven't used it but it doesn't look like it has had any updates in over a year. Reviews mention a lot of crashes...doesn't inspire confidence. Plus if I am to spend $69.99 on it then I would at least like it to have more than 3.3 stars.

Comment: I use it every day on macOS Mojave. I suggest download trial to make your own opinion :-)

Comment: @Andrew, but how do we know which changes to keep? `Ours` or `theirs`. Is there a better way, or me making a mistake somewhere? Btw I can't open my project settings from xcode as double clicking on my project from the left navigation pane throws `workspace integrity` `could not load project` !

Comment: I would always keep `ours` as that is your **original** version. If you have merged the changes already into your `project.pbxproj` then you need to `revert` the `merge` or go back to your original branch and start the merge process again (this is usually the easiest approach). I have never been able to fix the conflicts once it has been merged. It is always best to avoid them.

Comment: I am upgrading from 0.62.2 to 0.63.3 using the manual method. Do you think we have to touch `project.pbxproj` ?

Comment: @Kasra looking at the [react-native upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.62.2&to=0.63.3) there are changes that have been made to the `project.pbxproj` file, most look like they are pod changes so most issues will be fixed running `pod install`, after you update the `podfile`.

Comment: Yes, this issue is solved, now I am facing this: https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/485#issuecomment-708311002

Comment: @kasra unfortunately comments are not for long discussions. I would suggest writing up the issue that you are having, include enough for a minimum example, and post it as a new question and hopefully someone will be able to help you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

After updating react native to version 0.55 from 0.51, everything seemed to function normally in the local mode. But the production build fails.

I fixed this by upgrading react native once again from 0.51, and keeping my changes instead of theirs almost all the time.

May be there should be more detailed explanation in the documentation regarding the kind of issues one run into, by picking the wrong changes.